# Parts of speech of "Those" and its usage

Tags: grammar

I assume that **That** and **Those** both are same parts of speech. But I have some question:

I know this is correct -

> The room is stuffed with the dead animals **that** I have hunted.

Now I know that in this usage "that" can be used for both singular and plural nouns. But can I also use "those" in place of "that" when plural noun is there or will it be wrong?

[N.B so far I haven't seen such usage]

Comment: I think that *that* works as a relative pronoun. On the other hand, *those*, though can work as a pronoun, can't be used as a relative pronoun, as far as I know.

Answer (score 3):

"That" and "those" are both pronouns. However, while they are both demonstrative pronouns, "that" is also a relative pronoun.

The demonstrative pronouns are "this", "that", "these", "those". They can replace nouns, for example: *Give me that!; I want those*.

The relative pronouns (e.g. "that", "which", "whom") are used to start a relative clause, as in your case. Another example would be: *Please, give me the bag which is on the chair.* or *I want the grapes that you haven't started eating yet.*

In these two examples "that" cannot be substituted by "those" because "those" does not have the function of a relative pronoun.